# Best practices for documenting exception which caused by unknown arguments

Tags: java, javadoc

This is more of a best practices question. I hope that it's okay to ask this question here. I am creating an interface that will be used as part of our API. I have a method called `getSomeObject()` which has a complected logic behind the scenes and returns `SomeObject`. Behind the scenes I am calling the method which throws `IllegalArgumentException`, so there is a possibility that my `getSomeObject()` method may throw this exception. The problem I have is that the user of the API is not familiar with inner workings of the API and wouldn't understand why the exception was thrown. Since the argument is created inside my method and the user doesn't even know that this argument exists. I was trying to document it, but the reason for this exception would confuse the user of the API. So my question is, what is the best way to go about the situation like this? What is the correct way to document this exception?

Comment: Wrap it in your own exception explaining the reason why it happened.

Comment: My advice would be to catch the IllegalArgumentException inside your getSomeObject() method and throw an exception specific to your api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` from a method that does not take any arguments is indeed quite confusing.

I suppose you get that exception if something outside of `getSomeObject` is not properly defined. So you could maybe throw an `IllegalStateException`, and document it with an explanation in your javadoc:

```
@throws IllegalStateException If member variable xyz is not initialised.  
                              This can happen if method `init()` has not been   
                              called before `getSomeObject`.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response assylias. What if the user doesn't know about method `init()` either?

Comment: @robonerd In the end the user needs to be able to use your API properly. So I guess there are only 3 possibilities: (i) the user can take extra steps to avoid the IllegalArgumentException and you need to document those extra steps (ii) your code needs to do something to avoid the exception and should do it or (iii) at runtime, something can happen that makes your API unuseable and you should throw an appropriate exception, possibly checked, to let the API user know that something went really wrong (say database access not available for example).

Comment: My answer was related to case (i) or (iii).

Answer (score 1):

When you say that there is a possibility of your internal code throwing IllegalArgumentException , how are you handling it ? 
Is it caused by faulty input by the user ? 
if not then you should catch it and handle it and if still you have to throw it it has to be translated into an exception that the user can make sense 
Or is the chance of that happening unlikely and is purely theoretical? 
If this is a valid exception scenario that the user should handle you should throw an appropriate checked exception and declare it in your interface